# How to hide and show view on button click in react native?

Tags: react-native, show-hide

i m new to react-native

i have two buttons A and B ....  and two Views V1 and V2....by default V1 is visible and V2 is hidden .

How to achieve

On button B click- make V2 visible and hide  V1

On button A click- make V1 visible and hide  V2

Answer (score 1):

define your state:

```
state = {v1Visible: true, v2Visible: false }
```

in jsx:

```
{this.state.v1Visible && <View><Text>View 1</Text></View>}
{this.state.v2Visible && <View><Text>View 2</Text></View>}
```

and your button click functions:

```
onButtonAClick = () => this.setState({v1Visible: true, v2Visible: false})
onButtonBClick = () => this.setState({v1Visible: false, v2Visible: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the `state`

Create a render function for the specific views and render them conditionally with an `if/else` block

```
renderViews() {
   if (this.state.viewVisible) {
      return <View1></View1>
   } else {
      return <View2></View2>
   }
}
```

Place the method inside your render function like this `{this.renderViews()}` and toggle the state via the buttons and `this.setState({viewVisible: true/false})`